# Exclude all rows above a Table's databodyrange

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the databodyrange row number of a table and not the sheet row number

This code gives me the sheets row number which is 18 and not 1 that I am expecting

```
commentcode.DataBodyRange.Cells(commentcode.ListRows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Comment: So, `commentcode` should e the `ListObject`. Correct? What do you want to be returned? The row of the Table header?

Comment: Looking to your code and your stated expectation, I can suppose that you need **the last empty row in the table first column**, but the table row. If this understanding is correct, the title of the question has nothing to do with the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next way. I tried to not look at the question title, and tried deducing what you want showing in the code against your expectation. So, the next code will return the **table first empty row in its first column**:

```
Dim shFirstRow As Long, tblFirstRow As Long
   'Set the ListObject
   shFirstRow = commentcode.DataBodyRange.cells(commentcode.ListRows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
   tblFirstRow = shFirstRow - commentcode.HeaderRowRange.row
   Debug.Print shFirstRow, tblFirstRow
```